# Ticket channel name with numbers

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a support ticket system but I would like my channel to be named as: USERNAME-001.
Even if the old one is deleted, it's still USERNAME-002.
And at 300 it's 001.
I don't know if I was understood.
I would like to be a bit like the public discord bot: Tickety: http://prntscr.com/mwiqp5 
Because right now it's like: USERNAME-USERNAMEDISCRIMINATOR : http://prntscr.com/mwit8q

Ask me if you want more details on a part of the code or the request...

My code that creates the current channel:

`message.guild.createChannel(message.author.username + " - " + message.author.discriminator, "text").then((channel) => {`

Sincerely.

Comment: Make a counter and increase it as long as tickets are being created?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But the counter goes up even if a user has closed a ticket. And this up to 300 in number

Comment: Would you do that? That would be very kind of you: p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const counter = 0; // This has to defined in previous code. If I were you, I would use a database for this.
```

As I wrote in the comment, I would use a database for this where you countup with every ticket which is created on a Discord server.

Then you can use the following code:

```
var reached300 = false;

if (reached300 === true && counter !== 0) {
  counter -= 1;
} else {
  counter += 1;
}

if (counter === 300) {
  reached300 = true;
} else if (counter === 0) {
  reached300 = false;
}

var counterName;

if (counter <= 10) {
  counterName = `#000${counter}`
} else if (counter <= 100) {
  counterName = `#00${counter}`
} else if (counter <= 1000) {
  counterName = `#0${counter}`
} else {
  counterName = `#${counter}`
}

message.guild.createChannel(`ticket-${counterName}`, "text").then((channel) => {
 // CODE HERE
});
```

Comment: Exactly, I use a database where I store all the information about the ticket. (Database under MongoDB)

Comment: If you provide me more information about your database and its methods, I can try to help you. Did you understand the answer that I gave you? Did it help? @Niromash

Comment: No, I didn't understand it unfortunately, but what information do you want on the database? : http://prntscr.com/mz4e69
"ticket-6595" because I make the name of the ticket with a random number.

Comment: Oh I thought that you count up from 0 to 9999. Do you understand how you implement this (with the random number)?

Comment: No, but the random number was in the meantime.
But if you can make me a counter doing: "ticket-001" to "ticket-300" and then it goes back to one.
If you can do it, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Thanks but I have one error: here : counter +=
I think you forgot a piece x)

Comment: Try again please! :) @Niromash

Comment: I have to put it where the `const counter = 0;` ?
Because he tells me he's undefined.
Sorry I'm lost. x)

Comment: You should save this in your Database (in your case MongoDB I think so)

Comment: Uh, do you have a way for me to communicate all the code to you? Because I'm really lost....

Comment: I am sorry... I would really help but I am too busy for such big questions :/ Sorry